# Form, run multiple functions onsubmit only if previous were successful

Tags: javascript, forms, return, onsubmit

I have a form which onsubmit performs some functions. How can I be sure that func2(); is only performed if func1(); run successfully? And func3(); only if 2 and 1 did?

```
<form onsubmit="func1();func2();func3(); return false">
    <input type="text" id="start" name="start">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

For example one of the functions is like:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&amp;sensor=false&amp;region=it&amp;libraries=places"></script>
<script>
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.88994,12.51383);

var mapOptions = {
    zoom:16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: myLatlng,
    styles: [
        {
            featureType: "poi.business",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [
                    { visibility: "off" }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));

var input = document.getElementById('start');
var options = {
    types: ['geocode'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'it'},
    rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE
};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Studio medico'
});
}

function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = "Via Tiburtina 500, Roma";
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Other 2 are:

```
function boxappear() {
document.getElementById("percorsolink").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("percorsoform").style.display="inline";
}

function reducemap() {
document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.width="620px";
google.maps.event.trigger( map, "resize" );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's not about running one function *if the other one is succesful*, but *after an asynchronous operation is done*. In `calcRoute`, the route calculation API call is asynchronous; that means the function will return *before* the `directionsService` finishes creating the route. One solution is to modify `calcRoute` to take a callback:

```
function calcRoute(callback) {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = "Via Tiburtina 500, Roma";
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

        // If a callback was passed, run it
        if(typeof callback === "function") {
            callback();
        }

      }
    });
}
```

Then change your function call to pass the callback:

```
<form onsubmit="calcRoute(function(){ boxappear(); reducemap(); }); return false">
```

Side note: I wouldn't recommend inlining code in HTML attributes like that, is mixes structure and behavior, and can also become hard to maintain; I suggest looking into other ways of attaching events to DOM elements.

Comment: Works like a charm! :D Thanks!!
Is it possible to create a browser popup with an error if for some reason the asynchronous operation isn't done?

Comment: Probably, but I don't know how. The google documentation may provide an example.

Comment: I'll search! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "run successfully" do you mean completed? This is guaranteed, since your `onsubmit` is basically like a function body. You're not telling `onsubmit` to run the functions in parallel or giving it a list; rather, you're just executing them in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your functions to return `true` (success) or `false` (something went wrong).

```
function func1() {
  // do something
  return true;
}

function func2() {
  // do something
  if (!'someThingWentWrong') { return fale; }
  return true;
}

...
```

Then chain your functions like this in your form:

```
<form onsubmit="func1() && func2() && func3(); return false">
    <input type="text" id="start" name="start">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

The `&&` is the `and` operator. It first evaluates its first argument, and only if the first argument is `true` the second argument is evaluated. So, the `&&`-chain stops, when the first function returns `false`.